# dijit form select inside of custom widget not showing arrow

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've got a dijit/form/Select within a custom widget, and the dropdown arrow is not appearing.  I also need to set the width and height in style in order for the control to be readable and it does not seem to recognize selected attribute.  Any idea why this would be?  if I just use a regular HTML select control it works fine.

Widget:

```
define([
  ...
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
  "dijit/form/Select",
 ...
  "dojo/text!Templates/MarkTicketForm.htm"
], function (.., _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
   Select,
   ...
    MTFormTpl) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: MTFormTpl,
...
```

Template (MarkTicketForm.htm):

```
...
<select id="selectReach" style="width: 150px; height:20px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
                <option selected="selected">IV</option>
                <option>IVA</option>
                <option>IVB</option>
                <option>IVD</option>
                <option>IVE</option>
                <option>V</option>
                </select>

...
```

Thanks

Comment: A full runnable example on e.g. JSFiddle would be necessary to help...  or at least show the styles you are importing (are you even importing a Dijit theme and including its class in the body tag?  If not, that would be your problem)

Comment: I'm importing the claro class and assigning it in the body tag of my main page which calls the widgets.  I'm trying to build a plunk.

Thanks